# JavaScript Mapping an API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object which is being creating in the Context Component of my React application.

It looks something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      roles: [
        { role_type : { display : Manager }},
        { role_type : { display : Accounting}},
        { role_type : { display : Developer }},
      ],
   },
}
```

I am then making an API call which returns an array of role_type objects. The return looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "a49-a2a5-fcce",
    "link": "organizations/roletypes/a49-a2a5-fcce/",
    "code": "MANG",
    "display": "MANAGER",
    "description": "MANAGER"
  },
  {
    "uuid": "681fbe",
    "link": "organizations/roletypes/681fbe/",
    "code": "SUPSPEC",
    "display": "Support Specialist",
    "description": "Support Specialist"
  },
  {
    "uuid": "0331ddccf",
    "link": "organizations/roletypes/0331ddccf/",
    "code": "PROJMANG",
    "display": "Project Manager",
    "description": "Project Manager"
  },
]
```

If my API call is successful I want to update each of the role_type objects whose display matches a display of the API response.

I have a working solution:

```
updateRoleTypes = () => {
  for(roleType in this.state.roles) {
    for(responseType of APIresponse) {
      if(responseType.display === this.state.roles[roleType].role_type.display) {
         this.setState( this.state.roles[roleType] : responseType)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My teammate asked me today if I can do this without the for loop.  I'm not really sure how to change my code to get rid of the for loop though :/

Comment: do you know what the array map function does? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map have you tried it?

Comment: in addition to @azium comment, you should consider updating the whole array from the state at once. Doing it in the loop cause multiples of useless component re-rendering

Comment: I did look at the map function and it seemed like that would work if I needed to loop over just a single array.  I couldn't figure out how to map over two arrays simultaneously.

Comment: This doesn't look a working solution. The line `this.setState( roles[roleType] : responseType)` should not work. `roles` is not defined and if `roles` should be `this.state.roles` then you would replace it with a different data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
updateRoleTypes = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const names = prevState.roles.map(role => role.role_type.display.toLowerCase())
    const updated = APIresponse.filter(r => names.includes(r.display.toLowerCase()))
    return {      
      roles: [
        ...prevState.roles.filter(row => !APIresponse.find(responseRow => responseRow.display.toLowerCase() === row.role_type.display.toLowerCase())),
        ...updated,
      ],
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are able to modify the `state`? If this is the case you can modify the data type of the `roles` to be an `object of objects` (This could use the `code` of the role as the key of the object), instead an `array of objects`.This will help you to access and check each role with certain `key`.

This way you should be able to use run just one loop to check if the new `role` exists in your `state` and update it if is the case.

**Code**

```
const state = {
  roles: {
    "MANG": { role_type: { display: "Manager" } },
    "ACCT": { role_type: { display: "Accounting" } },
    "DEV": { role_type: { display: "Developer" } }
  }
};

const response = [
  {
    uuid: "a49-a2a5-fcce",
    link: "organizations/roletypes/a49-a2a5-fcce/",
    code: "MANG",
    display: "MANAGER",
    description: "MANAGER"
  },
  {
    uuid: "681fbe",
    link: "organizations/roletypes/681fbe/",
    code: "SUPSPEC",
    display: "Support Specialist",
    description: "Support Specialist"
  },
  {
    uuid: "0331ddccf",
    link: "organizations/roletypes/0331ddccf/",
    code: "PROJMANG",
    display: "Project Manager",
    description: "Project Manager"
  }
];

const updateRoleTypes = newRoles => {
  let _roles = state.roles;
  newRoles.forEach(nR => {
    if (_roles[nR.code]) {
      _roles[nR.code].role_type = nR;
    }
  });

  return _roles;
};
```

This will return your mutated `state` you just have to `setState` with the new value.

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-water-owgn6) is a working example in a sandbox.